# Monitor has developed a white shine in the middle

Tags: display

the problem is hard to describe, i was getting a coffee and when i came back, my monitor looked like this. The Edge (3cm) seems to be normal, everything else has a white tint. There's burn in after 5 minutes, which fades away after time. It seems the problem is stronger when the monitor is turned on recently and cold and gets better the longer it runs.

I tried a different cable, input (HDMI) und Laptop - does not make a difference. Monitor model is Dell U27115H

Does anyone have an idea, which part is broken?

Testpicture everything green:
[image: Testpicture full green]

Normal browsing with monitor menu open (has the same problem):
[image: Normal browsing]

Answer (score 0):

There is a **Built-in Diagnostics** where you have to unplug your DisplayPort/HDMI cable from the monitor. [Here is the link for your monitor](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_display/dell-u2715h_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf) (PDF) from this page: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/dell-u2715h/docs.

See the Troubleshooting pp. 55-58.

**Brightness Problems**

> Picture too dim or too bright

- Reset the monitor to Factory Settings(Factory Reset).
- Adjust brightness & contrast controls via OSD."

Hope this helps.